# Type 'MenuItem' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Tags: ios, swift

Why am I getting the error: Type 'MenuItem' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'? It was working before. One of the things I changed was modifiers from [String]? to [Modifier]? Is that producing the error? If so, why? Stackoverflow wants me to keep saying things because it's too little description relative to the amount of code that I displayed below. Still needing to add text.

```
struct MenuItem: Codable {

let itemId: String
let name: String
var modifiers: [Modifier]?
var photoUrl: String?
var quantity: Int
var unitPrice: Int
var sizeAddOnPrice: Int
var toppingsAddOnPrice: Int
var totalPrice: Int
var totalModifiersPrice: Int
let description: String
var size: String
var toppings: [String]?
let category: String

init(itemId: String, name: String, modifiers: [Modifier]?, photoUrl: String?, quantity: Int, unitPrice: Int, sizeAddOnPrice: Int, toppingsAddOnPrice: Int, totalPrice: Int, totalModifiersPrice: Int, description: String, size: String, toppings: [String]?, category: String) {
    self.itemId = itemId
    self.name = name
    self.modifiers = modifiers
    self.photoUrl = photoUrl
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.unitPrice = unitPrice
    self.sizeAddOnPrice = sizeAddOnPrice
    self.toppingsAddOnPrice = toppingsAddOnPrice
    self.totalPrice = totalPrice
    self.totalModifiersPrice = totalModifiersPrice
    self.description = description
    self.size = size
    self.toppings = toppings
    self.category = category
}

init?(itemId: String, payload: JSON) {
    guard
        let name = payload[ParamKey.name].string,
        let photoUrl = payload[ParamKey.photoUrl].string,
        let description = payload[ParamKey.description].string,
        let category = payload[ParamKey.categoryName].string,
        let unitPrice = payload[ParamKey.basePrice].int,
        let size = payload[ParamKey.size].string
        else { return nil }
    self.itemId = itemId
    self.name = name
    self.photoUrl = photoUrl
    self.description = description
    self.category = category
    self.unitPrice = unitPrice
    self.size = size
    self.sizeAddOnPrice = 0
    self.toppings = nil
    self.toppingsAddOnPrice = 0
    self.totalPrice = (unitPrice + sizeAddOnPrice + toppingsAddOnPrice) * quantity
    self.totalModifiersPrice = (sizeAddOnPrice + toppingsAddOnPrice) * 2
    self.quantity = 1
    self.modifiers = payload[ParamKey.modifiers].arrayObject as? [Modifier]
    }
}
```

Comment: `Swift` can autogenerate all the code for `Codable` if and only if all it's fields are `Codable` too. Obviously `Modifier` is not `Codable`.

Comment: Did you try adding the `Decodable` protocol to `MenuItem` and still got that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the inner structs conform to `Decodable`/`Codable` also and remove struct `init` it'll be automatically generated

```
struct Modifier: Codable {
    // add properties 
} 
struct MenuItem: Codable {

    let itemId: String
    let name: String
    var modifiers: [Modifier]?
    var photoUrl: String?
    var quantity: Int
    var unitPrice: Int
    var sizeAddOnPrice: Int
    var toppingsAddOnPrice: Int
    var totalPrice: Int
    var totalModifiersPrice: Int
    let description: String
    var size: String
    var toppings: [String]?
    let category: String

    init?(itemId: String, payload: JSON) {
        guard
            let name = payload[ParamKey.name].string,
            let photoUrl = payload[ParamKey.photoUrl].string,
            let description = payload[ParamKey.description].string,
            let category = payload[ParamKey.categoryName].string,
            let unitPrice = payload[ParamKey.basePrice].int,
            let size = payload[ParamKey.size].string
            else { return nil }
        self.itemId = itemId
        self.name = name
        self.photoUrl = photoUrl
        self.description = description
        self.category = category
        self.unitPrice = unitPrice
        self.size = size
        self.sizeAddOnPrice = 0
        self.toppings = nil
        self.toppingsAddOnPrice = 0
        self.totalPrice = (unitPrice + sizeAddOnPrice + toppingsAddOnPrice) * quantity
        self.totalModifiersPrice = (sizeAddOnPrice + toppingsAddOnPrice) * 2
        self.quantity = 1
        self.modifiers = payload[ParamKey.modifiers].arrayObject as? [Modifier]
    }
}
```

You can also use

```
try content.rawData() // for payload: JSON) {
```

to `JSON` to data and then supply it to the `Decodable` class